# Melting a Df with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF

```
ID,     1,      2,      3              #Columns 
0,Date, Review, Average, Review # Observations
1,01/01/18 2,   4,      3      # Date and Review Score
2,02/01/18 1,   2,      4      #Date and Review Score
```

I'm attempting to melt this DF into the following, using the below code gets me close:

`df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID'],var_name=['Store'],value_name='Score').fillna(0).set_index('ID')`

this procudes:

```
           Store    Score
ID      
Date        
01/01/18    1       Review
01/01/18    1       2
02/01/18    1       1
```

What I would like to do is remove the 'Review' and have it within its own column, something like the following

```
           Store    Review Type Score
ID      
Date        
01/01/18    1,      Review,    1
02/01/18    1,      Review,    2
```

I've attempted to do wide to long, but I *think* I would need to use some level of multiindexing here, or maybe i'm over thinking it.

Considerations :

my DF is 824 columns long and 324 rows 
my variables are row wise, along the date with the ID being the column header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for...

starting with this dataframe, which I believe is what you have:

```
    ID           1         2       3
0   Date       Review   Average   Review
1   01/01/18     2         4       3
2   02/01/18     1         2       4
```

assuming that you do your `pd.melt()` you are then left with:

```
new_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ID'],var_name=['Store'],value_name='Score').fillna(0).set_index('ID')

          Store    Score
ID      
Date        1      Review
01/01/18    1      2
02/01/18    1      1
Date        2      Average
01/01/18    2      4
02/01/18    2      2
Date        3      Review
01/01/18    3      3
02/01/18    3      4
```

then you can do something like:

```
# sort index so all the 'Date' values are at the bottom
new_df.sort_index(inplace=True) 

# create a new df of just the dates becuase that is your review types
review_types = new_df.loc['Date']

# rename column to review types
review_types.rename(columns={'Score':'Review Type'}, inplace=True)

# remove new_df.loc['Date']
# new_df = new_df.drop(new_df.tail(len(review_types)).index).reset_index()

# UPDATED removal of new_df.loc['Date']
# I recommend removing the date values by doing this and not using .tail()
new_df = new_df[~new_df.index.str.contains('Date')].reset_index()

# rename ID column to Date
new_df.rename(columns={'ID':'Date'}, inplace=True)

# merge your two dataframes together
new_df.merge(review_types, on='Store')
```

which gives you:

```
    Date      Store  Score  Review Type
0   01/01/18    1     2     Review
1   02/01/18    1     1     Review
2   01/01/18    2     4     Average
3   02/01/18    2     2     Average
4   01/01/18    3     3     Review
5   02/01/18    3     4     Review
```

Comment: very very cool, perfectly does what I wanted, splitting the DF and the merging was a masterful step bravo. May I ask why does the `['Date']` column go to the bottom of the DF when you sort the index? as the code to drop the row goes to the bottom

Comment: @Datanovice after you use melt, your index contains both numbers (the actual dates: '01/01/18') and the value `'Date'` so the index is sorted in ascending order: numbers will come first then your alphabet characters. That is why I used `new_df.tail()` to remove them. If you want the value `'Date'` on top you can remove with `head()` instead

Comment: @Datanovice you can also remove the date by doing `new_df[~new_df.index.str.contains('Date')]`, which is probably a better approach than my original example. I recommend doing that instead of what I did.

Comment: Hey @chris, just come back to this and have to say it's a brilliant answer for a very messy data set, my thanks again